# How to connect multiple VPNs using OpenVPN on Windows 7 at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, openvpn

I work most of the time remotly from home. To gain access to the different Networks we use OpenVPN.

I would like to connect to all of them (three, sometmes four) at once, so I don't have to switch all the time.

My setup is Windows 7 and a PC with only one NIC. Is it possible to connect mltiple VPNs at once?

Comment: As long as the remote networks use different subnets, and the VPNs use different subnets **and** they don't all make themselves the default route.

Comment: As a clarification of Cry Havok's comment above, see [this superuser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second?lq=1) for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cisco VPN along with any other VPN.

Comment: I think the question starts with *how to*, so can you expand your answer to explicitly specify as to how the OP can connect to multiple VPNs with Cisco, if that's possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Open the command prompt as Administrator

```
net start openvpnservice
```

This allows you to manually connect to all VPNs at once. If you want to you can set it to automatically connect by itself without any interaction.

Open services.msc. Set the OpenVPNService to Automatic.