# Connect to multiple VPNs?

Tags: vpn

I need a way to connect to multiple VPNs.  It's to access camera systems and resources that are on different networks as a client.  One VPN could be a company network, and another a city network.  Is there a straightforward way to do this?  I've experimented with setting up multiple virtual machines in virtualbox already, and I'd like to avoid having to have a full OS installation for every VPN I want to connect to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect multiple VPNs using OpenVPN on Windows 7 on the same time?](http://superuser.com/q/151228/97028).

Comment: What VPN is that?

Comment: See [this superuser answer](http://superuser.com/questions/547507/stop-windows-7-from-clobbering-one-vpn-when-connecting-to-a-second?lq=1) for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

this link will probably answer you question:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/multiple-vpn-clients-in-parallel

You should consider using ssh instead of vpn, or using vpn on Virtual Machines with some minimalist OS (some tiny Linux distro, or something highly customizable like Arch Linux)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We don't really have a choice as to if it's SSH or VPN.  So far, it's been all VPNs.  We're given access by clients to their VPN so we can access a server on their network.

Comment: Then VM with some minimalist OS is your only choice. I have done some research and it looks like most people that have tried otherwise have stumbled on issues with packets being redirected to the wrong vpn.